# Add class to html root

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add a class to the root html tag at the top of the page when a button is pressed. The only code I have come across is for adding classes to div elements with ids.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class="THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CLASS TO BE ADDED" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
```

Start presentation

I have tried to adapt this code but nothing works ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#addClass").click(function () {

      $('para1').addClass('presentation-started');

    });

    $("#removeClass").click(function () {

      $('#para1').removeClass('highlight');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your code? (of what you have tried)... Where is the button?

Comment: Please include all your source code relevant to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use:

```
$('html').addClass("someclass")
```

to add a class and

```
$('html').removeClass("someclass")
```

to remove it.

If you have a button with `id="mybutton"` then you would use like this:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('html').addClass("someclass")
});
```

*If* your code does not follow the button element on the page, you also need to wrap your jQuery in a DOM ready handler (otherwise the `click` handler will never be connected):

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
        $('html').addClass("someclass")
    });
});
```

This is just a handy shortcut version of `$(document).ready(function(){...}):`

**Update using your new example**

So, using your existing example, it would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#addClass").click(function () {
            $('html').addClass('presentation-started');
        });

        $("#removeClass").click(function () {
            $('html').removeClass('highlight');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in i assume it would be .removeclass to get rid of it

Comment: @Jess: Indeed. Added to answer.

Comment: and .toggleClass can toggle it on and off.
Also, the vanilla JS for this (needs a polyfill for IE9 and above) would be:
`document.documentElement.classList.add("myClass");`

Comment: @Jacque Goupil : Their example has two different classes, so `toggleClass` would not appear to be useful. The question is clearly jQuery, so introducing raw JS and polyfill requirements is not recommended :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I know, I just hate searching for an answer and landing on only JQuery-based ones, so it might help anyone passing by one day.